# Showing only certain Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

We have about 10 custom home page components.   I need to show one of them on pages for a custom object called "Registration".

There is a setting in the Setup/App Setup/Customize/User Interface, to "Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages".  The problem is that it will show all 10 custom components on all pages, while I only need one displayed.  Any ideas how to do that?

As a side note, this custom component consists of JavaScript that injects a custom lookup window link into the standard page layout.

Answer (score 0):

How about you combine the components into one component and then use javascript inside the component to determine (based on document.location) whether to show the sub-components.